# CSS - Different header images for fluid grid layout website

Tags: html, css, image, dynamic, fluid-layout

EDIT : read further then the next 5 lines! My problem is not the logic of doing different css for mobile, tablet and desktop (`@media` query) - the problem is to change the `IMAGE.SRC` attribute FROM INSIDE CSS.

I'm trying to make a new fluid website and I'm trying to create 3 different header images:

1. Mobile header image (low res)
2. Tablet header image (medium res)
3. Desktop header image (high res)

(all the images also vary in aspect ratio)

How do I get this to work?

Currently I've tried to simply change the SRC in CSS for each CSS SECTION (mobile, tablet, desktop)

Like this:

```
#img_header {
   src: url(img/header_m.png);
}
```

We all know that this doesn't work :D also I don't want to use `background-image` instead.

What is the proper way to do this?

Should I hack into the generated javascript code from Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 and change the .src from there ?

I'm sure there is a css way, so tell me guys. Thanks

UPDATE: I should have said that I already use media queries...

Here is my css:

```
/* Layout für Mobilgeräte: 480 px oder weniger. */
.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 97.826%;
    padding-left: 1.0869%;
    padding-right: 1.0869%;
}

#div_header {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#img_header {
    src: url(img/header_m.png);
}

/* Layout für Tablet-PCs: 481 bis 768 px. Erbt Stile vom: Layout für Mobilgeräte. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .gridContainer {
        width: 93.451%;
        padding-left: 0.7744%;
        padding-right: 0.7744%;
    }

    #div_header {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    #img_header {
        src: url(img/header_t.png);
    }
}

/* Desktoplayout: 769 bis maximal 1232 px.  Erbt Stile von: den Layouts für Mobilgeräte und Tablet-PCs. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .gridContainer {
        width: 89.1614%;
        max-width: 1232px;
        padding-left: 0.4192%;
        padding-right: 0.4192%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #div_header {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    #img_header {
        src: url(img/header.png);
    }
}
```

NOW that you have read everything, you should imagine that I can't change the `img.src` from inside css..., I think the only way to do so is to hack into the unformatted auto generated javascript from adobe DW cs6, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've now set another div inside the div_header, and give that child div a background image and a hardcoded width and height ( matches the individual images ), so i've faked a  tag that now have ability to define (backgound-) image source via css instead of defining **attribute** of image source ;)

thanks anyway for your answers

Answer (score 1):

If you are using single image in diff resolution then you need not to do take 3 images. Take the bigger image (for desktop size) and write the below css

```
<header><img src="img/header_m.png" /></header>
```

CSS

```
header img{max-width:100%}
```

I believe you are aware of media queries  http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

**To change foreground image**

If you want to change foreground images for different devices then try z-index

```
.header{
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;  height:auto}

img:first-child{
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    z-index:-1; width:200px
}
img{
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    z-index:10; width:200px
}
```

Change the z-index value for respective device width.

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/5vpG7/70/

Comment: but OT wants different images in img tag ?

Comment: Thank you.:) He has mentioned 3 diffrnt resolution images so I assume it is the same image in diff resolution. Anyways in that case he can go with media query

Comment: u typed exactly what i've typed , 3 images , with wiferent resolution and aspect , my problem is to SWICH the images with css, the only problem is " crs:url(img/image.png) " see my update

Comment: @Ace check my updated answer. I assume you are trying to change the foreground image

Comment: z-index doesnt does what i want. the MOBILE website version is developet to minimize the load speed and the kb's of the site... if i use zindex or visibility, it still loads the HIGH RES images in the mobile version....

Comment: Then using the bg image is the only option

Comment: yup exactly than bg images would be best because images in img tag will take HTTP requests as per no of images.......

Comment: you can discuss further more overhere :- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15567/front-end-developer

Comment: when i use bg image instead , what is the propper way to site the div so that if fits the image resolution ?

Comment: Give header width as width:auto; height:auto or dont write width and height

Comment: if i type w and h = auto, the div will be 0x0 px, "auto" does reference to the child objeckts , but bg-image is not a child...

Comment: then give min-width/height min-width: px; width:auto; min-height: px; height:auto

Comment: that it would be always the size of min width / min height, either in desktop view...

Comment: mention in % and display:block

Comment: forget about it , see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSS3 media queries` for your desired results.....

And I think you should read this article it will help you :-

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 1):

You can do different images by using **media queries**

**Mobile**

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
 Your image for mobile
}
```

**Tablet**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px){

Your image for tablet
}
```

Comment: see my update , the problem is not the image querry , it is the part inside of it .

Answer (score 0):

......................

Now used to **media query css**

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 800px) { 
// your css code here 

 }
```

***[more info about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)***

Comment: Rohit but OT wants different images in img tag ?

Comment: as i sait , it's a automatic generated code vrom dreamweaver cs6, and if u know it , you should also know that is already has media querrys...